# Reading AVRO from Azure Datalake in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, avro, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I am trying to read eventhub data (AVRO) format. I am having issues loading data into a dataframe in databricks.

Here's the code I am using. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong

```
path='/mnt/datastore/origin/zone=raw/subject=customer_events/source=EventHub/ver=1.0/*.avro'

df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro") \
    .load(path)
```

Error

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI:
```

I did try using some code to remove the error, but I am getting the syntax errors

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                     .builder()
                   .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","/mnt/datastore/origin/zone=raw/subject=customer_events/source=EventHub/ver=1.0/")
                   .getOrCreate()



SyntaxError: invalid syntax
File "<command-265213674761208>", line 2
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
```

Comment: Looks like you're using Python, but trying to run Scala/Java code... Thus `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Relative path in absolute URI

You need to specify the protocol rather than use `/mnt`

For example, `wasb://some/path/` if reading from Azure blobstore

You can also exclude `*.avro` since the Avro reader should already pick up all Avro files in the path

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-avro.html#python-api

And if you want to read from EventHub, that exposes a Kafka API, not a filepath, AFAIK

Comment: Is there any way to use regex to retrieve date range  files. Ex: last two weeks. Files are in this format /2020/03/25/*.json . Each day separate directory saved the data

Comment: @SajithVijesekara Store the data in a partition format like `path/to/data/year=2020/month=03/day=25/*.json`. Then `spark.read.format("json").path("/path/to/data")` can be filtered on the inner partitions on any date range. This is how Hadoop/Hive prefer to query data, which is what Spark uses